# Show footer on last page only

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I want to add footer on my report, but only on the last page. I followed [this tutorial](http://bi-person.com/9-ssrs-sql-server-reporting-services/22-how-to-display-footer-only-on-last-page) which was successful, but it leaves space for the footer on *all* pages.

How can I get rid off that space for the footer on all pages except the last one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only think of the following solution for your problem:

First - don't use the build in Footer. Instead, use a sub-report that will contain your footer details.

Now, you need to define the sub-report as thin as possible in the main report (while in the actual sub-report - arrange your data as you want).

Then just implement the same concept as described in the link that you provided - means that you need to define an expression in the sub-report visibility filed.

attaching a demonstration that explaining the 'using sub-report' idea:

[image]

**EDIT**
I did some research - If you follows the instructions provided by the link in your question but Strech the rectangle to cover all the footer area, then your are good - the footer will not be displayed until the last page:

**This how I arranged the Rectangle over the footer:**

[image]

**Middle Page (you can see that the footer's rectangle is hidden:**

[image]

**Last Page (footer is visible):**

[image]

Comment: Yes but globals only can be used in page header and footer. I mean to say globals.pagenumber

Comment: You right, sorry didn't thought about it . I edited my answer - see now

Comment: But the red part is the footer of the main report ? If yes, then where is the subreport ? Thankx