# Textbox at End of the Report in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, footer, reportingservices-2005

I am using SSRS 2005 Reporting Service. The Report page filled with all three sections and the table is in the body. I would like to add one rectangle having 4-5 textboxes at end of the report, meaning it should positioned to exact before the footer of last page but should not repeat on each page.

I have tried with putting rectangle in the footer but it repeats on each page. If rectangle is in body then it will be next to table that means if table have 2-3 rows then the whole page will cover in first half of the report but the another half of the report leave blank. Instead i want that rectangle at the end of the last page of the report.

For more, please see the attached image.[image]

I have so much googled for this but didn't find any related answer. Please guyz help to out of this.

Any help would be appreciate.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14848689/1340960) answer on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the rectangle in the footer and setting its Hidden property to the following?

```
=Globals!PageNumber <> Globals!TotalPages And Globals!TotalPages > 1
```

Comment: Hi JC, sorry to late replay. Ya i have tried with this but it leave a blank space in footer every page for that rectangle. It should not leave that space and at the end of the report will use that space in order to display the rectangle. Do you have ant idea about it?