# SSRS Show Textbox on last page separately

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, ssrs-2008, report, reporting

I need to display a Textbox in the body of the report, but it has to be on a separate last page. It is actually a Word file that needs to be shown in each report, but seeing as how the [only way](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1e82550e-bda3-4b6f-9be3-4f25e03d51c0/can-i-embed-a-word-doc-into-a-ssrs-report?forum=sqlreportingservices) to accomplish this is to put the file to the Report Server and then access it with a link, I decided to copy the contents of the file to a Textbox.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1751512/1340960) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14848394/1340960) question on SE are similar, however it is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding items with appropriate page breaks to the report.

Say I have a simple report with a table and a textbox:

[image]

The end result looks about what you'd expect:

[image]

However, we can force the textbox onto a new page by embedding it in a Rectangle and setting the Rectangle to always be preceded by a page break:

[image]

[image]

Now the report displays the textbox on the last page:

[image]

[image]

Tables themselves can also have page breaks, but since it's just text with no dataset it makes sense to me to use a Rectangle here.

Comment: I actually figured it out 10 minutes ago and used exactly the same thing :) Thank you very much for the effort!