# ssrs how to create a textbox appearing at the last page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

<s>It is getting late here.</s>

Anyway let's crack on

I want my textbox to appear on the last page of my report

I cannot put it into a footer, I don't want to create a rectangle and then put a textbox in it

This link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168177/ssrs-show-textbox-on-last-page-separately) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751512/ssrs-show-value-only-on-last-page-in-body-of-report) does not help.

I'm getting loco. Any helps are more than welcomed

Comment: Why is placing the textbtox in a table or rectangle with a page break before it not an option?

Comment: Hi @StevenWhite because I don't want to have a page break.

Comment: Can't you just place it at the bottom of the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing you can do is create a dataset which query would be something like

```
select 'this is the text I want in the last page' as txt
```

then you can create a one column tablix with this dataset and place it after all the other elements in the report and it will show in the last page.