# Push items to bottom of report

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, reporting

I'm trying to create a report with some controls "anchored" to the very end. The difficulty is that I can't add this to the page footer because the report could span multiple pages leaving a giant white space at the end of each report if I decide to toggle visibility. The items I have should only appear on the very last page and be positioned just above the footer.

For example, in this scenario, I need the letter's closing signature, titles, etc. positioned at the very end of the last page the report spans.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848394/show-footer-on-last-page-only)?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to adding a sub report you could try the suggestion below.

It all depends on how you data is laid out in your report whether it could work for you.

If all the data required to populate the controls exists in the report dataset why not add an outer lever of grouping that encompasses the entire dataset. You could do this using a dummy column containing 1 for example.

Just add a footer to this group and put your data in the group footer.
You can additional rows as necessary to the group footer.

This footer will always appear as the last row(s) in the tablix